# Why is this person not affected by bullets?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-defenders

In "The Defenders" (*Marvel's The Defenders*, S01E08), there is a scene in which Detective Knight shoots Bakuto with a gun but nothing happens to him.

Why?

As far as we know, none of the five fingers of [The Hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hand_(comics)) are impervious to damage. They can be cut so I assume they can be shot, too.

**How was Bakuto able to survive the gunshot?**

Comment: Yeah, it's strange. In the comics [he gets killed by a sword](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/8191031/IMG_0633.PNG), and in *Iron Fist* [he gets severely injured by a sword](https://image.prntscr.com/image/nUbs8YR5TEGtmmI_7iLQVA.png), and then [killed by a sword](https://image.prntscr.com/image/taDI4q_mRtiVYRiEBDF69Q.png). He comes back because they can resurrect themselves, but that implies death, which implies mortality, and everything we see shows they take damage like normal people would (except the bizarre gunshot in *Marvel's The Defenders*). Strange.

Answer (score 1):

We're kind of speculating but Bakuto is different from the other leaders of the Hand in that **he's already died**.

Bakuto was killed by Davos in *Iron Fist* S1E12 *Bar the Big Boss*.

The others, apparently, have *extended lives* rather than being resurrected...certainly Alexandra wouldn't be that worried about her illness if she was invulnerable.

What we know of resurrected beings comes from Nobu who was killed by Stick in *Daredevil* and, again, it seems the only way to kill a **resurrected** person (in this universe) is to *decapitate them* (Nobu, Harold Meachum) as Colleen does shortly thereafter.

Comment: Alexandra clearly states in an early episode that she has died several times. Her worry now is because they are out of the substance that allows them to resurrect and she fears they won't be able to acquire more before her impending death.

Comment: It's *implied*, you might be right...although she never actually says she's died..just that she's seen the darkness on the other side any times.

Comment: she said she died, also she said that she had a daughter in early life, she said elektra that they both have seen the darkness after death. so this means she had died, several times,

Comment: Alexandra also states (I'm paraphrasing) that even if you're immune to being killed, you can still end up rotting from the inside (hinting at the unnamed disease she has that is killing her) out

Answer (score 0):

In that event it could be that Bakuto was wearing some kind of armor inside his clothes. when Misty shots him, it seems bullets hit Bakuto, but didn't do much impact as bullets normally would.

Bakuto comes forward while he gets shots and it shows that he just couldn't need to think about that. He wasn't worried it seems, plus the reason he may knew that hand would end that night and he wants Coleen to be with him. Maybe just escape from other hand members at that time, let them die and rebuild his own hand later with Coleen.

I know, all these are speculations. Hope this may helps at least a bit